# Border thickness for Telerik's RadMaskedInputBaseStyle in Silverlight when content is invalid

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik

How do I increase border thickness for RadMaskedInputBaseStyle (or RadMaskedDateTimeInput by Telerik) in Silverlight only WHEN it is red indicating that the input contains invalid entry. 
My XAML looks like this

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadMaskedDateTimeInput">
    <Setter Property="IsValidationHintVisible" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Comment: You'll have to dig into the control template and find the border that's set to visible for the Invalid state in the `VisualStateManager` for that control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if a style isn't available as a property of the control, then you will find it buried somewhere in the control template (as Chris W alludes to in the comments).

To see the source for a proprietary control template like one of Telerik's, open up Expression Blend and click "Edit Template" on an instance of the control.  If you do that for the `RadMaskedDateTimeInput`, you will notice the validation-related visual states making reference to an element named "ErrorElement".  Scroll down, in the control template source, and you will see that is declared as follows:

```
<Telerik_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ValidationTooltip x:Name="ErrorElement" Opacity="0" TooltipPlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="{StaticResource Theme6}" TooltipContent="{TemplateBinding DisplayErrorMessage}" TooltipContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ErrorMessageTemplate}" />
```

Ok, so it's another control called `ValidationTooltip`.  This control *does* have a `BorderThickness` property exposed, so if you like, you should be able to simply set that property in a targeted global style.  Something like this should go in your resource dictionary:

```
<Style xmlns:Telerik_Windows_Controls_Chromes="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chromes;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"  
    TargetType="Telerik_Windows_Controls_Chromes:ValidationTooltip">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</Style>
```

Comment: I applied the code proposed above and it solved my problem! Additional hints are also very valuable.